# com.microsoft.azure .servicebus.primitives.ServiceBusException

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

I can't connect to my queue on azure account using java code. It seems that the problem is the network. I can to connect with my private network but not with the company network.

I have this message error:

> Exception in thread "main" http://com.microsoft.azure .servicebus.primitives.ServiceBusException:   Error{condition=amqp:connection:framing-error, description='connection aborted', info=null}.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that the problem is the network. I can to connect with my private network but not with the company network.

Yes, you are right.  I also find the simlar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues/37) on the github. It seems that your company firewall restriction which blocks all traffic on **ports 5671** and **5672**. We could get more information from [AMQP 1.0 in Azure Service Bus and Event Hubs protocol guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide).

> Azure Service Bus requires the use of TLS at all times. It supports connections over TCP port 5671, whereby the TCP connection is first overlaid with TLS before entering the AMQP protocol handshake, and also supports connections over TCP port 5672 whereby the server immediately offers a mandatory upgrade of connection to TLS using the AMQP-prescribed model. The AMQP WebSockets binding creates a tunnel over TCP port 443 that is then equivalent to AMQP 5671 connections.

If possible, you could ask permission to open 2 ports in your company firewall.